# How to change the legend position when transfer ggplot2 to plotly using `ggplotly`?

Tags: r, ggplot2

As the code below, I constructed a plotly from a ggplot, and want to change the position of the legend.

```
df <- data.frame(n=1:10, Var1 = rnorm(10), Var2 = rnorm(10))
data_long <- melt(df, id = "n")
a <- ggplot(data_long, 
            aes(x = n, y = value, colour = variable, group = variable)) + 
      geom_line() 
ggplotly(a) %>% layout(legend = list(x = 0, y = 0), yaxis = list(title = ""))
```

The ggplot looks like
[image: ggplot]

But the plotly looks like

[image: plotly]

Part of the legend title is still on the top of the graph.

Comment: Welcome to our site! Questions about R programming (or indeed other languages) are off-topic here - see our [help/on-topic]. However, I think this question can be migrated to Stack Overflow for you. Bear with us while the migration process takes place. (If you want to post on Stack Overflow yourself, rather than wait for us, just make sure you delete the post here rather than cross-post on both sites at the same time.)

Comment: (By the way, it's usually best not to call your dataframes `df` because there is already [an R function by that name](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/Fdist.html), for the density function of the F distribution!)

Comment: I have to admit that I call all of my data frames `df` (and didn't know what the built in does).  I rreallllllly wish R would not be so liberal with the built in one and two letter names.

Comment: @MatthewDrury I feel your pain! Some of the t-distribution ones catch me out sometimes too: if one wants to write what in one's mathematical notes is "p subscript t" as `pt` (similarly for `qt` and `rt`) or if one uses `dt` to indicate change in time...

Comment: Yah, the change in time one is particularly painful (I just checked, `dx` and `dy` are not taken).

Comment: I have the same question. Did you find an answer Julia ? Changing the position of the ggplot does not change the position of the ggplotly.

Answer (score -1):

You can use legend.position argument:

```
a <- ggplot(data_long,
            aes(x = n, y = value, colour = variable, group = variable)) +
    geom_line() +
    theme(legend.justification=c(0,0), legend.position=c(0,0))
```

Comment: Thank you apruden! But the plotly plot still keep the legend title on the top of the plot after `ggplotly`